# sqlite update a column with itself

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I got a table like this

```
a  b  c
-- -- -- 
1  1  10
2  1  0
3  1  0
4  4  20
5  4  0
6  4  0
```

The b column 'points' to 'a', a bit like if a is the parent.
c was computed. Now I need to propagate the parent c value to their children.

The result would be

```
a  b  c
-- -- -- 
1  1  10
2  1  10
3  1  10
4  4  20
5  4  20
6  4  20
```

I can't make an UPDATE/SELECT combo that works

So far I got a SELECT that procuce the c column I'd like to get

```
select t1.c  from t t1 join t t2 on t1.a=t2.b;
c
----------
10
10
10
20
20
20
```

But I dunno how to stuff that into c

Thanx in advance
Cheers, phi

Answer (score 1):

You have to look up the value with a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
UPDATE t
SET c = (SELECT c
         FROM t AS parent
         WHERE parent.a = t.b)
WHERE c = 0;
```

Comment: Thanx CL, I knew it was trivial :) My brain is just not SQL formatted yet :), cheers.

Comment: I wanted to post after your reply but my post goes up before your breaking the sequentiality of the evolution. I am disoriented with this editor. Phi

Comment: Does it mean I should have post my question regarding perf between the 2 solutions to another 'question'. I wanted to ask this question to you as you seem knowledgable regardingstackoverflow handling.

Comment: I red a bit of it (takes time) is there a way to 'chat' with someusers, for instance to ask for a second opignon before posting, or like in this case to ask for complementary infos that may not be usefull post (like the perf of the 2 solutions, how should have done this ?)

Comment: You could ask a new question ([help/on-topic]), but then you'd get a comment "Why do you doubt your measurements?"

Comment: Because I don't know what SQL does, even with an query plan (explain) I have hard time to figure out what cost what. But I think I am getting there :) thanx for all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107222/discussion-between-phi-and-cl).

Answer (score 0):

I finnally found a way to copy back my initial 'temp' SELECT JOIN to table 't'. Something like this

```
create temp table u as select t1.c  from t t1 join t t2 on t1.a=t2.b;
update t set c=(select * from u where rowid=t.rowid);
```

I'd like to know how the 2 solutions, yours with 1 query UPDATE correlated SELECT, and mine that is 2 queries and 1 correlated query each, compare perf wise. Mine seems more heavier, and less aesthetic, yet regarding perf I wonder.

On the Algo side, yours take care not to copy the parent data, only copy child data, mine copy parent on itself, but that's a nop, yet consuming some cycles :)

Cheers, Phi